# React-Native: "TypeError: Network request failed" On Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm going crazy with this error on my Android App.

I'm doing a signup in my app and I use the fetch method to an API that works. (I have tried to insert data with CocoaRestClient and it works!)

I have already done the login  with the fecth and it works perfectly, but the problem is about the signup method.

So:

**Registrazione.js**

```
class Registrazione extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            FirstName: this.props.hasOwnProperty('FirstName') ? this.props.FirstName : '',
            LastName: this.props.hasOwnProperty('LastName') ? this.props.LastName : '',
            FiscalCode: this.props.hasOwnProperty('FiscalCode') ? this.props.FiscalCode : '',
            identity: this.props.hasOwnProperty('identity') ? this.props.identity : '',
            Email: this.props.hasOwnProperty('Email') ? this.props.Email: ''
        }
    }
    registrazione () {
        let ctrl = true;
if(ctrl){
        if(global.isSafe){
            Actions.sceglipassword({
                Email: this.state.Email,
                FirstName: this.state.FirstName,
                LastName: this.state.LastName,
                FiscalCode: this.state.FiscalCode
            })
        }
        else{
            Actions.creazioneutente({identity: this.state.identity, FirstName: this.state.FirstName, LastName: this.state.LastName, FiscalCode: this.state.FiscalCode, Email: this.state.Email}) 
            }
                }
    };
```

And Then I call **ScegliPassword** Page:

```
class ScegliPassword extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Password: '',
            PasswordRepeat: ''
        };
    }


    registrazione(){
        let ctrl = true;
        if(
            utility.isEmpty(this.state.Password) || utility.isEmpty(this.state.PasswordRepeat)){
                ctrl = false;
                Alert.alert("Error");
              }

        else if(this.state.Password != this.state.PasswordRepeat){
                ctrl = false;
                Alert.alert("Error");
              }
        if(ctrl)    
        {
            let identity = {
                "APPNAME":
                        {
                            Username: this.props.FiscalCode,
                            Password: this.state.Password
                        }
            }
                Actions.creazioneutente({identity: identity, FirstName: this.props.FirstName, LastName: this.props.LastName, FiscalCode: this.props.FiscalCode, Email: this.props.Email})
        }
    }
```

Then there is an action to **CreazioneUtente**

```
class CreazioneUtente extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
    }

    creaUtenza(){
        Utente.creaUtente(this.props.identity, this.props.FirstName, this.props.LastName, this.props.FiscalCode, this.props.Email)

        .then((data) => {
            global.utente = new Utente(data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

And there I call the **Utente**.creaUtente

```
static creaUtente(identity, FirstName, LastName, FiscalCode , Email) {
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('Identity', identity);
        formdata.append('FirstName', FirstName);
        formdata.append('LastName', LastName);
        formdata.append('FiscalCode', FiscalCode);
        formdata.append('Email', Email);

        console.log(Configuration.base_url.rest + Configuration.apiRoutes.signUp)
        console.log(formdata)

        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            fetch(Configuration.base_url.rest + Configuration.apiRoutes.signUp , {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                body: formdata
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                if(responseData.Error){
                    Alert.alert("Errore");
                }
                global.utente = responseData;
                resolve(responseData)
            })
            .catch((err) => {reject(err)})
        })
    }
```

In the fecth I pass the link of the API for the signup (it's an https://***.com link)

Now if I print the "formdata" in console log, I receive the correct data that I have inserted with the form.

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <uses-library
          android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
          android:required="false" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

When I try to do the signup, I receive this kind of error (in my console):

```
{ _parts: 
[ [ 'Identity',
{ "APPNAME": { Username: 'TNNFRZ77H01G273V', Password: '12345' } } ],
[ 'FirstName', 'Fabrizio' ],
[ 'LastName', 'Tonno' ],
[ 'FiscalCode', 'TNNFRZ77H01G273V' ],
[ 'Email', 'Fabrizio.tonno@email.com' ] ] }
{ [TypeError: Network request failed]
line: 24122,
column: 31,
sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }
```

I don't know how solve this problem... 
Can you help me? Thank you.